# How do I legitimately find the codes for the door and vault in chapter 2-3?

Tags: super-paper-mario

My daughter is currently playing through Super Paper Mario on the Wii and has reached Chapter 2-2, the one where you "break" the vase and are put to slave labour to earn a million Rubees... unless you're smart enough to escape.

The problem is for the life of me I can't remember how to get the codes to the door on the 2nd floor or the vault hidden on the 3rd (and she won't let me take the controller and work it out for her).

I've had a look at a few walkthroughs and they all just *give you the code* for the vault.

So, outside of this obvious cheat, how would you legitimately get the codes for the doors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it involves a lot of use in the rubees room.

Take a look around, there's a couple of characters that are willing to give you some "info" in exchange for some rupees.

First, earn 100 rubees in the generator room and take them to the room on the 1st floor, where the prisoner on the left will exchange them for the code to the locked room on the 2nd floor (the wheel room)

In the wheel room you need to grab 10,000 rubees (doesn't take TOO long in that room) and them use them to pay the prisoner in the break room who can only be seen by flipping, here will exchange them for the code to the vault.

Hope all this helps.